# PHP two syslogs;

Tags: php, apache, xampp, error-logging, syslog

I'm trying to do a feature with such a functionality:
I've got a custom error handler but I want to set it up i cooperation with default server `syslogger`. I'm using `Xampp`.
So I need to send data to two `syslogs` at same time.
Is it possible in `PHP`?

Comment: I'm trying to send message to external syslog with socket and simultaneously write error message to Apache syslog. I'm using set_error_handler.

Comment: I've figured it out :) Just need to add error_log with 0 parameter at the top of the function

Answer (score 0):

You have to use different facility with [openlog()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openlog.php) and open/close log for each switch between these, due to lack of log handle being passed to syslog()